# Static variable shadowing global

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, static, initialization

I am trying to create an object using `placement new` (I know to use smart pointers, this is just to learn). My code is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


using namespace std; // please excuse this

// if you change like 19 to arr1 (or any other var name) instead of arr and line 40 to arr1 then it works

struct A
{
    int in = 999;
    A()
    {cout << "A ctor\n";}
    ~A()
    {cout << "A dtor\n";}
};

char arr[sizeof(A)];

class B
{
    public:
    static char arr[sizeof(A)];

    const static A* a_obj;

    B()
    {
        cout << "B ctor\n";
        //cout << (a_obj->in) << endl;
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout << "B dtor\n";
    }
};



const A* B::a_obj = new(arr) A;


int main()
{
    B g;
}
```

I have created a `global array` named arr and another `array` named `arr`in `B`. It seems like when I do my `placement new` the `arr` being used is from the class as I get what I think are linker errors.

Why is this happening? why isn't the `global arr` being used? If i change the `placement new` to use my renamed `global array` it works. I think it has to do something with `lookups` but I don't have a concrete answer.

Comment: Please share the linker errors.

Comment: Please read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It should explain about scopes, variable shadowing between them, and how can you resolve it. One such way to resolve them is scope resolution operator (`::`), via which you can use `arr` from global scope like this: `::arr`.

Comment: You can disambiguate with `::arr` and `B::arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ 2017 Standard (12.2.3.2 Static data members)

> 2 The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class
>   definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other
>   than cv void. The definition for a static data member that is not
>   defined inline in the class definition shall appear in a namespace
>   scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at
>   namespace scope, the name of the static data member shall be qualified
>   by its class name using the :: operator. **The initializer expression
>   in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its
>   class** (6.3.7).

So in this definition of the static data member

```
const A* B::a_obj = new(arr) A;
```

the unqualified name `arr` is at first searched in the scope of the class `B`. And the class B indeed declares such a name

```
static char arr[sizeof(A)];
```

If you want to use the name from the global namespace then use the qualified name

```
const A* B::a_obj = new(::arr) A;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    const static int N = 10;
    static int n1;
    static int n2;
};

const int N = 20;

int A::n1 = N;
int A::n2 = ::N;


int main() 
{
    std::cout << "A::n1 = " << A::n1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A::n2 = " << A::n2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A::n1 = 10
A::n2 = 20
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The reason arr is attribute to the class B and not the global scope is due to unqualified name lookup rules.

Specifically:

> Static data member definition For a name used in the definition of a
>   static data member, lookup proceeds the same way as for a name used in
>   the definition of a member function.

Meaning:

```
struct X {
    static int x;
    static const int n = 1; // found 1st
};
int n = 2; // found 2nd.
int X::x = n; // finds X::n, sets X::x to 1, not 2
```

If you are intrested you can see more information here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

As people suggested to get what you want just use:

```
const A* B::a_obj = new(::arr) A;
```

Comment: thank you, thought it was something like that but wasn't sure at all.