# Why Rust allows declaring same variable name twice in a scope?

Tags: rust

First time I am encountering a typed language allowing to declare a variable name twice in the same scope. Wouldn't there be a chance to override an existing variable by mistake? What advantage does it bring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rationale behind allowing variable shadowing in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860476/what-is-the-rationale-behind-allowing-variable-shadowing-in-rust)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [a chapter in the book about this.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing)

> Shadowing is different from marking a variable as mut, because we’ll get a compile-time error if we accidentally try to reassign to this variable without using the let keyword. By using let, we can perform a few transformations on a value but have the variable be immutable after those transformations have been completed.
>
> The other difference between mut and shadowing is that because we’re effectively creating a new variable when we use the let keyword again, we can change the type of the value but reuse the same name. For example, say our program asks a user to show how many spaces they want between some text by inputting space characters, but we really want to store that input as a number

```
let spaces = "   "; // String
let spaces = spaces.len(); // number
```

In short, it allows you to "modify" a value, in a way that is technically immutable. Rust ensures that you cannot use the shadowed variable, so it's perfectly typesafe.

I'm no Rust expert, but from a language design perspective it's an interesting thing to encourage. But I think the point is to *discourage* the use of mutable values whenever possible by allowing you to immutably override a name with a new type and value.

Comment: I wouldn't say it modifies, since it creates a completely new variable and will delete both the new and old one once the scope finishes. Shadowing is done compile-time, so no dynamic casting or modifying occurs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48227487/7652095

Comment: Agreed, which is why I put “modified” in quotes. It implies the new value at least depends on the old value, but is in fact a new immutable value.